# linkedin bot by adding people automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, nightmare

I try to learn the web scraping by using nodejs and nightmarejs.

I wanted to create a bot that can connect to my linkedin account, then look for a technology, as javascript for example, then add the link of each profile in the sheet into a table, and with this table, I wanted to use a loop with "for" to click on the each link. At the end I send an invitation for each profile on the sheet.

Here my code :

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })

 var langage = process.argv[2];

 var urls = [];
 nightmare
    .viewport(1000, 720)
    .goto('https://www.linkedin.com/')
    .type('#login-email', '**********@gmail.com')
    .type('#login-password', '*********')
    .click('#login-submit')
    .wait(3000)
    .type('#main-search-box', langage)
    .wait(3000)
    .click('.search-button')
    .wait(2000)
    .click('a[data-li-vertical-type="people"]')
    .wait()
    .evaluate(function () {
 var link = [];
    $('.primary-action-button.label').each(function(i, item) {
    link.push($(item).attr('href'));
    urls = link;
})

    }
})

.run(function (err, nightmare) {
if (err) return console.log(err);
console.log('Done!');


for (var i = 0; i< urls.length; i++ ) {
nightmare
    .goto(urls[i])
    .click('#IF-reason-iweReconnect')
    .wait()
    .click('.btn-primary')
}    


  });
```

I type node script.js 'jquery' into the console and it told me that 'urls is not defined', and I don't undestand where is my mistake.
If you can help me, it would be really helpful :)
Thank you,

Kev

Comment: Someone to helpe me? :)

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting two common pitfalls with Nightmare.  First, variable lifting - like you're attempting to do with the `urls` array - does not work like you might think.  Variables from the enclosing scope are not available to a scope inside an `.evaluate()` because of how the `.evaluate()`d function is passed to Electron.  Fixing this is reasonably easy: return the array from the evaluated function and have an intermediate call to `.then()`.  Something like (edited for brevity):

```
.evaluate(function () {
    var link = [];
    $('.primary-action-button.label').each(function(i, item) {
      link.push($(item).attr('href'));
    })
    return link;
 })
 .then(function(urls){
    nightmare.goto(urls[0]) ...
 })
```

For a more in-depth explanation, you may want to read [Variable Lifting and `.evaluate()`](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-examples/blob/master/docs/common-pitfalls/variable-lifting.md).

The second issue you're almost immediately going to hit is looping over something and using a Nightmare instance to execute some command.  By design, Nightmare is asynchronous, and as such looping as you have it will not work.  You will also probably want to give [Async Operations and Loops](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-examples/blob/master/docs/common-pitfalls/async-operations-loops.md) a read.  Lifted relevant vanilla JS example from there:

```
var urls = ['http://example1.com', 'http://example2.com', 'http://example3.com'];
urls.reduce(function(accumulator, url) {
  return accumulator.then(function(results) {
    return nightmare.goto(url)
      .wait('body')
      .title()
      .then(function(result){
        results.push(result);
        return results;
      });
  });
}, Promise.resolve([])).then(function(results){
    console.dir(results);
});
```